# .net core rc2 - Package dependencies are not resolved

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a solution with two class libraries (.NET Core), named ProjectA and ProjectB.

In the project.json file of ProjectA, I add a reference to ProjectB like so:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "ProjectB": ""
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Package dependencies must specify a version range.

Not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ProjectB` package must specify what version of `ProjectB` you want.  This would be the same as the `version` property of `ProjectB`'s `project.json` file.  So if `ProjectB`'s `version` property is set to "1.0.0", you would add this to your dependencies:

```
"ProjectB": "1.0.0"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had just figured it out and was posting an answer to my own question when I got your reply.

But what I don't understand is this specific version number requirement in rc2. In prior versions, we just needed to include the project in the dependencies list without a specific version number and it would still resolve.

Comment: Sounds like it's either a bug, or an intentional fix in the dotnet cli.  Either way, it might be good to [open an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues)